# Beginning of a line with blank-spaces

Tags: vim

My text contains five lines (5th line contain two blank-spaces at the beginning) and I'm at the middle of the first one. How could I go to the beginning of the 4th line with the Vim editor? I thought I could use `5G` command, but it didn't work as I wanted.

Comment: @Zanna No, both command bring me to the first character of the line and not at the first blank of the line

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>5</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>

The `5G` gets you to the first non-blank character of your 5th line; pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>0</kbd> moves to the start of the line.

By the way, do you know about https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Or, you can opt for `set nosol` in which case if you're at the start of a line and you move `5G` you'll be at the start of line 5. `help startofline`

Comment: I'm learning Vim with Vim-advantures so far. Therefore, I cannot use `Home` to do that.

Comment: If you don't have a home key (I don't) you can press `0` instead

Comment: Upvoted :) Probably `0` is more standard than the home key? I learned `0` originally but never knew home could do the same thing

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend `0` over `home`. Additionally, you could even use `|` to achieve the same thing as `0`.